# How do I add a specific meta-tag to all the pages of a site?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I want to prevent Google from indexing my website. I know I need this meta tag added to the header.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

How can I add this meta-tag to all the pages of a site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module for this, in order to add meta tags to every page of your site:

[image]

If you want to do it by coding, it is possible to implement the [theme_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x) hook to add the meta tag manually:

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$variables)
{

    $noindex = [
            '#tag' => 'meta',
            '#attributes' => [
                'name' => 'robots',
                'content' => 'noindex',
            ],
        ];
    $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$noindex, 'noindex'];
}
```

(more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913739/add-meta-tag-to-head-in-drupal-8)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'd prefer if i can do this by code, with a hook for example ?

Comment: @usethe23, It is also possible. I have just edited my answer to add this possibility.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add a `robots.txt` file with the following content in your docroot:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You can find more information about this in [The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Comment: Note that this prevents crawling, not (necessarily) indexing ([details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35657571/1591669)).